# Firebase Authentication using Google redirect, redirects to my login page

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

```
 firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);

        firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function (result) {
            if (result.credential) {
                // This gives you a Google Access Token.
                var token = result.credential.accessToken;

            }
            var user = result.user;

        }).catch(function (error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            console.log(error)
            // ...

        });



   // Start a sign in process for an unauthenticated user.

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

        if (user) {

         $state.go('home');

        }
    })
```

I am trying to have Google Sign-in, but it always redirects me back to my login page and then after a some time it redirects to home page. After I click the sign in button, it redirects to the Google auth and returns back to the login page. How can this be avoided?

Comment: Can you clean up your code a little? There's an extra bracket/missing bracket somewhere and it's hard to tell what parts are being hit in what order.

Comment: k i ll , my exact query is while using firebase auth using google redirect i get a delay , u jus use this code on a signup and it redirects to the page where u had  sign-in  button and after few secs redirects to the page where is route is specified.

Comment: ya nw its edited..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always calling signInWithRedirect regardless of the auth state. You should call that when you know the user is not signed in. You can do something like this:

```
    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function (result) {
        if (!user) {
          // User not logged in, start login.
          firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
        } else {
          // user logged in, go to home page.
          $state.go('home');
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      console.log(error)
      // ...
    });
```

Comment: Ya i used this, but again it redirects me to login page and after a few secs its redirected to the main home page. I am looking forward for a resolution to overcome that redirect to login page and then home..

Comment: Now the flow is: "login-->google-auth-->login(stays for few secs)-->home "        I was looking for:  "login-->google-auth-->home.."

Comment: That is the expected current behavior. SignInWithRedirect will redirect back to the original page for sign in completion (loads an iframe, talks to the Firebase Auth backend and then signs in the user and saves the user to web storage before succeeding). That could be more pronounced on slower devices/networks.

Comment: Has anything changed since this question was asked? I am in 2020 and i have the same issue with very slow auth and flow like 'login-->google-auth-->login(stays for few secs)-->home'

Comment: I see this same behavior with the official auth demos, so I guess not.